# Customize Gerrit sign in page

Tags: gerrit

I have styled my gerrit landing page and other review related pages, however, none of the style settings seem to work for gerrit Sign In page. Even the header/footer pages in $site_location/etc/ doesn't seem to work. Any idea how to get it working?